# How to test rendering a partial for each object with rspec 3.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, render

Here is what I've found in the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/view-specs/view-spec):

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "widgets/index" do
  it "displays all the widgets" do
    assign(:widgets, [
      Widget.create!(:name => "slicer"),
      Widget.create!(:name => "dicer")
    ])

    render

    expect(rendered).to match /slicer/
    expect(rendered).to match /dicer/
  end
end
```

but it doesn't make a difference if I write this in the view

```
<%= render @widgets %>
```

or this

```
<% @widgets.each do |widget| %>
  <p><%= widget.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

---

Then I decided to try this (source the same):

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "rendering locals in a partial" do
  it "displays the widget" do
    widget = Widget.create!(:name => "slicer")

    render "widgets/widget", :widget => widget

    expect(rendered).to match /slicer/
  end
end
```

but it works only for rendering one object i.e. for

```
<%= render @product %>
```

and not for

```
<%= render @products %>
```

---

So how do I test that my list of widgets renders a partial for each widget?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the `rendered`string simply returns what the view actually rendered (as one might expect), the behaviour is as expected.

`expect(rendered).to match /slicer/` simply asserts that the rendered string contains the word `slicer`, and not whether or not the partial view was actually rendered.

A quick way to solve this is to match the `rendered` string with something that is **only part of the partial view**, like so:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "widgets/index" do
  it "displays all the widgets" do
    assign(:widgets, [
      Widget.create!({ name: "slicer", body: "this is the slicer body"}),
      Widget.create!({ name: "dicer", body: "this is the dicer body"})
    ])

    render

    expect(rendered).to match /this is the slicer body/
    expect(rendered).to match /this is the dicer body/
  end
end
```

Assuming this partial view:

```
<h3><%= widget.name %></h3>

<p><%= widget.body %></h3></p>
```

Of course, you can match the string based on anything you'd like.

Comment: But the question is the same (although it became more theoretical). If I can render one type of partial (`<%= render @product %>`) how can I render another type (`<%= render @products %>`)?

Comment: Well (and I might remember incorrectly here), but in your first example (`<%= render @product %>`) Rails will look for a partial named `_product.html.erb` and throw an exception if it's not found. In your second example, I think the exact same thing will happen (though I'm not entirely sure). To verify this, try to create a `_products.html.erb` partial and remove the `_product.html.erb` partial. To ensure you render `_products.html.erb` you need to call it explicitly `<%= render 'products', locals: { products: @products } %>`. Did that make sense?